# Why am I getting an Access Denied on importing a PST file in Exchange 2010 SP1?

Tags: exchange-2010, powershell, winrm

I am trying to test importing a .PST file directly from its original location on a remote machine with the New-MailboxImportRequest cmdlet in Exchange 2010 SP1. I have no trouble importing the file if it is located on a file share, but I don't understand why I can't import a file from other places on the remote hard drive if I am using DomainAdmin-level credentials.

Here is my powershell:

> [PS] C:\Windows\system32>New-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox Administrator@mydomain.com -FilePath '\Win7-Test-1\c$\pst_files\test1.pst'
>
> Unable to open PST file '\Win7-Test-1\c$\pst_files\test1.pst'.
>   Error details: Access to the path '\Win7-Test-1\c$\pst_files\test1.pst' is denied.
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (0:Int32) [New-MailboxImportRequest], RemotePermanentException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : C1C65BA8,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.NewMailboxImportRequest
>
> [PS] C:\Windows\system32>

I have confirmed that I can do a simple dir of the remote directory using the same PowerShell prompt, so not sure what the problem is.

> [PS] C:\Windows\system32>dir  \Win7-Test-1\c$\pst_files\
>
> Directory: \Win7-Test-1\c$\pst_files\
>
> Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
>
> ----                -------------     ------ ----
>
> -a---         9/21/2010   3:46 PM     271360 test1.pst
>
> -a---         9/21/2010   3:46 PM     525312 test2.pst
>
> -a---         9/21/2010   3:46 PM     271360 test3.pst

I read about enabling CredSSP for multi-hop over WinRM, so I thought maybe that would work but what I did to enabled it didn't work. I ran both of these commands on the Exchange Server to no avail. (Yes, I closed the PS window and opened a new one after running the cmdlets.)

> Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server
>
> Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer *

What do I need to do for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mailbox Import and Export process is handled by Exchange MRS component. If you check the Microsoft Exchange Mailbox Replication service properties, you will see the service is running under “Local System account”. That means the file share location you specified in the New-MailboxExportRequest or New-MailboxImportRequest doesn’t have permissions to Exchange Trusted Subsystem.

The solutions as you guessed enable Read/Write permissions to Exchange Trusted Subsystem for the network location (NTFS and Share permissions). Try again.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook is not required on the server - this is Exchange 2010.  You cannot use the c$ share - create a new share where your mail files are, everybody full control.  The share should be on a drive hosted by a computer which is in the same domain as the exchange server.

Answer (score 1):

The share on which the PSTs reside needs to have the Exchange Trusted Subsystem with read/write access added to the ACL.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in a location that's read-only is it?

PST's need to be in a location that's writeable even if you're not actually changing them.

Comment: No, the folder has default permissions and I've confirmed that the Administrator account I'm using on the server has full control.